# Large project example?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we are planning to build larger robotic project (industrial robots, many sensors, high and low level planning), and we are planning to use ROS. Is there some similar large project in ROS which can be used as an example?

What we are currently seeking is example of high-level design for large ROS project.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34815/large-project-example?/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-25**:
I feel like there should be a WikiBook or something for building a tutorial on how to do this.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-05-25**:
I think the notion of design patterns for a "large-scale" project is poorly defined without more info. I would ask you, what is it that you want ROS to do for you?

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-05-28**:
For now, the PR2 opening door is good example for large scale project. However, most of the tutorials are focused ether on how to run some demo or how to write some code to get some particular functionality. ...

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-05-28**:
... What I thing would be great starting point is some kind of top down example using some real task scenario, with explained high level design concepts which should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After two days of digging, I have found another similar project to PR2, the [Care-O-Bot](http://ros.org/wiki/care-o-bot), and I was able to run at least one [tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/cob_experimentation_days/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) with karma: 801 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I think "[Tips for larger projects](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch tips for larger projects)" may help you.
Nodes are intended to be of a small granularity, so having one node for one task (according to doc).
By the way, I think PR2 documentation could help you, as a complex system with several sensors.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-05-24**:
Thanks for the link, however this is tutorial about writing launch file for large project, what we need to know what is the right way to make entire system structure, if use one node for all planning or separate it into many smaller planning subnodes, probably what I would like to see is some graph.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-05-24**:
As said, nodes are at low granularity level, so that means that one node is doing one task, i.e, one node is doing planning, one is managing lasers, another one controls arm movements, motors ... I thinkgiving ROS a try through PR2 simulator can show you the way it is done. When running, you can ...

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-05-24**:
... use rxgraph to get the whole graph of nodes and topics. I suggest you to do so because theses graphs can be complex and would not be easy to see as an image (you can zoom in and out in with rxgraph)

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-05-25**:
Thanks, I haven't thought about running example in simulator.

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-05-28**:
So, I have tried to follow the tutorials for PR2 simulation but all of them are outdated and depend on packages which are no longer available or broken.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-05-28**:
I followed the [Basic PR2 controls](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls) tutorial that is mainly working on my machine (ROS electric, Ubuntu 10.04). Tutorials are often out of date but investigating stacks and packages usually bring solutions to the ajustements to do.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-05-28**:
At least, you can search & ask here for issues that have probably been solved.

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-08-29**:
Hi, liborw. hope you were able to simulate the large environment. I need to simulate a home/office environment. Hope u can help : http://answers.ros.org/question/42435/pointers-to-office-and-home-environment-in-gazebo/